# State space model

Tags: control, kinematics, wheeled-robot, two-wheeled

I want to design a LQR controller for my two wheeled mobile robot. While designing the controller, I need to find gain, K for the LQR which this required the state space model of wheeled mobile robot. My question is how to find the matrix A, B, C and D for this nonlinear system by using the equations below.

[image]

The outputs are x, y and theta while inputs are v and w.

Comment: A bit pushed for time right now, so can't really write a decent answer. Does [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/sjlevine/www/project_data/bicycle-planning/sjlevine_final_report.pdf) help?

Comment: Thanks sempaiscuba! But my wheeled robot is not a bicycle.

Comment: You can't. This system is nonlinear. You have to options. The first one is to linearize the system. The second is to design nonlinear controller. Also, it seems $v,w$ are the inputs and $x,y,\theta$ are the outputs.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad. The input is v and w while output is x,y and theta. Croco I know there is a way to linearise the equation but how to linearise it?

Comment: What you are looking for is probably [feedback linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_linearization). You will probably also find a more specific approach to your problem when searching for "feedback linearization unicycle".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're trying to apply a **linear** controller (the L of LQR) to a **nonlinear** system. In general, this doesn't work.

As an approximation, you could linearize the system. If the nonlinearities are small it's common to linearize about a nominal point such as $\theta=0$, but in your case this might not work well since it would eliminate any lateral dynamics.
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} = v
\\
\dot{y} = 0
\\
\dot{\theta} = \omega
\end{align}
$$

Another option would be to linearize every timestep. This could get expensive though as your feedback gain matrix, $K$, also needs to be recalculated each time.

Finally, a middle ground could be to linearize about several predefined points, e.g. $\theta=[-20,-15,-10,0,10,15,20]$. At each timestep you would separately compute the control action using the $K_j$ computed for each of these linearization points and then interpolate between those values based on the current $\theta$.